# Dash Heroku App: Couldn't find that process type (web)

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I am building Python Dash Heroku app, and I keep running into the following issue when attempting to add a Dyno to my project (heroku ps:scale web=1): **Couldn't find that process type (web).**

I have looked at the logs, and have the following H14 error:
2022-02-22T18:27:00.187432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=dash-app-nrdeering.herokuapp.com request_id=dfd42030-25ca-4be8-b579-d5f442b768c6 fwd="108.78.164.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-02-22T18:27:00.977750+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dash-app-nrdeering.herokuapp.com request_id=14aa1120-55bd-4a34-bd66-187c862b8e5c fwd="108.78.164.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I attempted to troubleshoot this by using the below link, but had no success. I used the command heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python to add the required buildpack. https://help.heroku.com/W23OAFGK/why-am-i-seeing-couldn-t-find-that-process-type-when-trying-to-scale-dynos

I followed the process on the Dash deployment site: https://dash.plotly.com/deployment

Below are the screenshots of my required files (.gitignore, app.py, Procfile):

**Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn app:server
```

**.gitignore:**

```
venv
*.pyc
.DS_Store
.env
```

**app.py**

```
# Import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import os
import dash
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from dash import no_update


# Create a dash application
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
```

I have explored other solutions on Stack Overflow but none were of use. I am beginning to get frustrated, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you. Is your `Procfile` named `Procfile` _exactly_, not `procfile` or `Procfile.txt` or anything else? Is it in the root (top) directory of your project?

Comment: I created the Procfile from scratch in VS Code, saved it as plain text file. I didn't add .txt at the end of the file name when I created. It is also in the root folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

The Procfile was the issue. It was in fact a text file. I thought I had gone through the necessary measures to make sure it was a Heroku Procfile. After fixing, my app now has a new error. Any thoughts on troubleshooting the below?

2022-02-22T19:27:09.711740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dash-app-nrdeering.herokuapp.com request_id=1caa5258-5038-4d08-80cf-b565809b505e fwd="108.78.164.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2022-02-22T19:27:10.408483+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dash-app-nrdeering.herokuapp.com request_id=9d83cdb6-9231-4811-91c7-ae335a13d140 fwd="108.78.164.134" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Also found the issue to my H10 error. For some reason the pandas module was not included in the requirements.text file. Pushed an updated version to git and the app now works.